# Ho to simulate 'this.props' inside React Component when using Enzyme for tests?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

So, my goal is to reach the func `cashedImageCheker` which must return the string , based on recived from `this.props` -> `imageFetchedURL` value. And my problem is that I cannot understand how to put this value into the corresponding func `cashedImageCheker` of my component `Banners`.

I tried to use Enzyme `.setProps({})` method to transfer mock props inside my testing Component, but for now I just gets `undefined`. Here is my test and component codes below.

Thank you for any help...

TEST FILE:

```
import React from 'react'
import { mount, shallow } from 'enzyme'

import Banners from '../'

describe('<Banners />', () => {
  it('imageFetchedURL must return true', () => {
    const Component = shallow(<Banners />)

    Component.setProps({
      imageFetchedURL: 'https://google.com/la-la-la/1.jpg'
    })
    const { imageFetchedURL } = Component.instance().cashedImageCheker()

    expect(imageFetchedURL.length).toBe(33)
  })
})
```

COMPONENT FILE:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Banners extends Component {
  cashedImageCheker = () => {
    const { imageFetchedURL } = this.props
    const imageFetchCached = imageFetchedURL && imageFetchedURL.length > 1

    return imageFetchCached
  }

  render() {
    const isLocalImgCached = this.cashedImageCheker()
    return (
      <div className='bannerWrap'>
        {isLocalImgCached}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Banners
```

Comment: "the func cashedImageCheker which must return the string" as currently implemented it doesn't return a string unless string is impty.

Comment: why would you need to destructure when you are returning a string from function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When testing your component, you can pass the props required by it while shallow mounting the component like

```
describe('<Banners />', () => {
  it('imageFetchedURL must return true', () => {
    const Component = shallow(<Banners imageFetchedURL={'https://google.com/la-la-la/1.jpg'}/>)

    const imageFetchedURL = Component.instance().cashedImageCheker()

    expect(imageFetchedURL.length).toBe(33)
  })
})
```

Also the major problem in code test case is that cashedImageChecker doesn't return you an object but a value and hence you need to write

```
const imageFetchedURL = Component.instance().cashedImageCheker()
```

instead of

```
const { imageFetchedURL } = Component.instance().cashedImageCheker()
```

Doing the above change will allow you to `setProps` and test the component method too.

```
describe('<Banners />', () => {
  it('imageFetchedURL must return true', () => {
    const Component = shallow(<Banners />)

    Component.setProps({
      imageFetchedURL: 'https://google.com/la-la-la/1.jpg'
    })
    const imageFetchedURL = Component.instance().cashedImageCheker()

    expect(imageFetchedURL.length).toBe(33)
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need to test the Component method inside themseft, not the render React method.

Comment: @MaxTravis, even if you get the props in render method, its probably the right way to test the function

Comment: Yes, but the question is about another side of the Component testing. I just need to test the component method with recived props inside it. What we do - it's some kind of bypassing in React )

Comment: And yes, your solution unfortunately does not work (

Answer (score 1):

> So, my goal is to reach the func cashedImageCheker which must return
>   the string , based on recived from this.props -> imageFetchedURL
>   value.

Based on this one way is this

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

import Banners from '../'

describe('<Banners />', () => {
  const url = 'https://google.com/la-la-la/1.jpg';
  it('imageFetchedURL must return true', () => {
    const Component = shallow(<Banners imageFetchedURL= url />)
    const imageFetchedURL = Component.instance().cashedImageCheker();
    expect(imageFetchedURL.length).toBe(33)
  })
})
```

> And my problem is that I cannot understand how to put this value into
>   the corresponding func cashedImageCheker of my component Banners.

For this query you must know a thing when something is connected to props then during testing you can pass it on as actual props as I have done it

```
<Banners imageFetchedURL= url />
```

> I tried to use Enzyme .setProps({}) method to transfer mock props
>   inside my testing Component

This is absolutely correct way too. It is another way of doing so.

But you were getting undefined because you were destructuring the return value which had nothing to do in your case.